# Merge Commits seem to change files on Github Pull Request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

We have two branches, master and test, as name suggest test is being used for feature testing and master is production. We firstly test our features and then move them into production on Github. After merging master branch new feature branches are created master branch includes merge commit from previous master merge. Here is the question, since these feature branches has merge commit from master merge, these commits seem to change test files which are already there. As image shows, for demo purpose I included a pr which is from master to test, even though there is no changes Github pr seems to change file. Why these merge commits change files even though there is no change at all. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: It isn't quite clear to me exactly what your process is. Are you merging feature branches into `test`, and then `test` into `master`, or are you merging `feature` branches separately into both `test` and `master`? Also, what strategy are you using for your merges? Usually this sort of thing happens when commits are rewritten (e.g. with squash or rebase), and therefore the same changes have different commit IDs on both the source and target branches.

Comment: We are merging seperately into both test and master. Then, we create new branch from master branch. Also, our merge strategy is standart merge via Github PR neither squash nor rebase.